# Reload .bashrc file for parent shell

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, source

I'm creating a script for managing my dotfiles and I want to source my `~/.bashrc`file automaticaly for the current bash.

But I found that when in my script write :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

it will source the .bashrc file for the execution of the script only. And as my shell is already started it will not reload the configuration.

Do you have a solution for reloading the file in the script-caller bash ?

(Correct me if you think I don't use the right terms)

Comment: Instead of _executing_ your script, _source_ your script. If done this way, the effects of the `source ~/.bashrc` line within your script will remain after the script finishes.  (Other changes made by the script will also remain.  So, it should clean up any unwanted temp variables or settings before it completes.)

Comment: OK great ! thanks but is there any way a method in a script to do it automatically ? If I want to execute it like so `./path/to/the/file.sh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of your script, you can do:

```
kill -USR1 $PPID
```

so that it will send the `USR1` signal to the parent process, which is the bash shell from which you run the script. In your `.bashrc`, you can trap this `USR1` signal to do whatever you like, such as

```
source ~/.bashrc
```